# PDF to doxygen - how to do it?

Tags: c++, documentation, pdf

I have a big pdf with the documentation for a project and I need to render this to doxygen (so take each function from the pdf and write it out into doxygen).

Any suggestions on how to do this quickly and effectively (other than doing it by hand)?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Programmers as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey **"Any suggestions/tools..."** are right there, in the text, _asking us to recommend a tool_ - do we read different questions?

Comment: Hm, must have missed that part.  Feel free to add your close vote, which you seem to have overlooked.  In any case, he does seem to be asking *how,* and his question would be valid if you removed the word "tools."

Comment: @suez: PDF is an output from doxygen, not an input.  The inputs to doxygen are things like code and xml comments.  I doubt that the tool you're describing exists, since that's not doxygen's purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will need some kind of OCR software to transform your PDF into some kind of machine readable ASCII text.

Second, since doxygen is a tool for creating docs from annotated source code, I assume you have that source code and your PDF docs refers to functions and classes in that source code. You will have to check if your ASCII-converted PDF text can be assigned uniquely and automatically to annotations of your source code. Since you did not post even the slightest example of how your docs and your source code look like, the only suggestion I can give you is to write a program for that task. The program should read the source code and the ASCII text and write the source code with doxygen compatible annotations. I would not expect to find an existing tool for that part.

Comment: last time I checked, Adobe Reader had an option "save as -> text..." that produced, well, perfectly machine readable ASCII text, where does OCR fit here?

Comment: @gnat: if this works depends much on the original source of the PDF, I would not expect that to work in general.

Comment: @DocBrown - OP doesn't mention any existing source code. May be the need is to generate documented header source files from PDF interface specification. Anyway your answer doesn't deserve downvotes.